# moving inline js to a seperate file

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover

I have onmouseover and onclick in my html and I would like to move them to separate js file (in js folder).

with onmouseover i do try however i can't make it work. it is supposed to be changing (just once) from img/cacti-edit.jpg to img/cacti.jpeg.
my html :

```
<div class="pic"> 
<img src="img/cacti-edit.jpg" alt="close-up of a cactus and its spikes"/>
</div>
```

my js:

```
let picture = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");

picture.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { picture.src='img/cacti.jpeg'; }, false);
```

console.log(picture)

log is : TypeError: picture.addEventListener is not a function.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/fixed.css')">Fixed width</li>
    <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('css/responsive.css')">Responsive</li>
</ul>
```

and in JS I have:

```
function swapStyleSheet(sheet) { document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", sheet); }
```

and I dont know at all how to move this onclicks into seperate js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the file, as you have shown you are getting an error from the event listener.

The reason is because getElementsByClassName() returns an array. You cannot assign a listener directly to an array. You need to access an element in the array and assign the listener to that.

```
let picture = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");

picture[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { 
picture.src='img/cacti.jpeg'; }, false);
```

Next, to add it to a separate file, simply add those functions to a file and import the file into your html.

For example:

Filename: test.js

Import line:

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByClassName()` selector will return an array, even if you have just one element to fit that query. You are trying to add an EventListener in a array, wich is impossible. 2 possible solutions are:

- Using a `for` loop in case you have more than 1 element with `pic` class:

  ```
  let picture = document.getElementsByClassName("pic");
  for(let pictureEl of picture) //You can use any loop that you find most convenient
       pictureEl.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { pictureEl.src='img/cacti.jpeg'; }, false);
  ```
- Select the array first element. This way you'll work with that specific div. Just add something in your query.

  `let picture = document.getElementsByClassName("pic")[0]; /*Since we are dealing with an array, index 0 represents its first element*/`

This should solve your problem. Comment if you need any clarification.